# AppArmor Permission denied loading profile

Tags: linux, permissions, apparmor

I am trying to start a docker-compose file on my VPS running Ubuntu 20.04, but I have problems with AppArmor. I have the following errors:

`systemctl status apparmor`

```
● apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-02-27 10:56:35 UTC; 1h 19min ago
       Docs: man:apparmor(7)
             https://gitlab.com/apparmor/apparmor/wikis/home/
    Process: 78 ExecStart=/lib/apparmor/apparmor.systemd reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 78 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 27 10:56:34 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[241]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "nscd".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[245]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "smbd".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[249]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "/usr/sbin/tcpdump".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confine>
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[247]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "/etc/init.d/nscd".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[247]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "smbldap-useradd".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[251]: /sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "traceroute".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 apparmor.systemd[78]: Error: At least one profile failed to load
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 27 10:56:35 vps-zap468762-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
```

When executing the `docker-compose up` command, the same errors appear. The aa-status returns 0 loaded profiles:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
0 profiles are loaded.
0 profiles are in enforce mode.
0 profiles are in complain mode.
0 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

I already tried:

- reinstalling docker and docker-compose
- reinstalling apparmor and apprmor-utils

I hope you can help me somehow, thanks in advance!